# Why after a click events keypress is happen two times?

Tags: javascript

I have click events when I click on the button and a keypress event's when I press enter key. But the problem is after a click on the button if I don't click on document and press enter key the `process()` function executes two times. I also try to fix it using the capture type but didn't find the solution.

> It it happening for button focus?

How can I fix this double execution problem?

```js
let

  button = document.querySelector('button'),
  input = document.querySelector('input');


button.addEventListener('click', process);
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13)
     process();
});


function process(){
  console.log(
     input.value
  );
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="sometext"/>
<button> Action </button>
```

Comment: Note: I was completely wrong before see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) regarding keypress. It should only fire once.

Comment: I know that. But thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But the problem is after a click on the button if I don't click on document and press enter key the process() function executes two times.

That's because the button has focus, and when you press Enter (or Space) on a focused button, it triggers a click. You can prevent that by calling `preventDefault` in the `keypress` handler.

```
if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 32) {
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let

  button = document.querySelector('button'),
  input = document.querySelector('input');


button.addEventListener('click', process);
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
  if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 32) { // ***
     e.preventDefault();                      // ***
  }                                           // ***
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
     process();
  }
});


function process(){
  console.log(
     input.value
  );
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="sometext"/>
<button> Action </button>
```

But `keyCode` is deprecated (so is [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event), the current recommendation is [`beforeinput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeinput) or [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event)), you might want to use [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead:

```
if (e.key === "Enter" || e.keyCode === " ") {
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let

  button = document.querySelector('button'),
  input = document.querySelector('input');


button.addEventListener('click', process);
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
  if (e.key === "Enter" || e.keyCode === " ") {
     e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
     process();
  }
});


function process(){
  console.log(
     input.value
  );
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="sometext"/>
<button> Action </button>
```

Comment: Very simple or I didn't get it :( so sad. [I didn't remember the button focus, need some rest] ...

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the button focus. That's why it works two times.